# Perco a sessão $_SESSION de uma view para outra view sistema php mvc próprio

Tags: php, mvc, session

Estou criando meu próprio [mvc](/questions/tagged/mvc) [php](/questions/tagged/php) para adquirir mais conhecimento.

Mas estou me deparando com uma coisa muita estranha, eu perco a `$_SESSION` de uma `view` para outra `view`.

**a.php ----- view a.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['teste'] = 'Funcionou';
echo $_SESSION['teste'];
?>
```

**b.php ----- view b.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['teste'];
// Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in    

var_dump($_SESSION);
// Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in NULL

?>
```

**Minha Classe da Session**

```
<?php
namespace Sis\Classes;

use App\Model\ClassLogin;
use Sis\Traits\TraitGetIp;

class ClassSession {

private $login;
private $timeSession = 1200;
private $timeCanary  = 300;

        public function __construct(){
                if(session_id() == ''){

                        ini_set("session.save_handler", "files"); //Cabeçalhos somente atraves de arquivos
                        ini_set("session.use_cookies", 1); //Habilita o uso de cookies
                        ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", 1); //Só pode habilitar a seção atraves de coockies
                        ini_set("session.cookie_domain", DOMAIN); //Só aceita coockies vindo do nosso sistema
                        ini_set("session.cookie_httponly", 1); //Só aceita script php e não deixa o javascript alterar o sistema

                        if(DOMAIN != "localhost"){
                                ini_set("session.cookie_secure", 1); //Para trabalhar com o SSL do servidor ativo
                        }

                        /*Criptografia das nossas sessions*/
                        ini_set("session.entropy_length", 512); // 
                        ini_set("session.entropy_file","/dev/urandom");
                        ini_set("session.hash_function", "sha256");
                        ini_set("session.hash_bits_per_character", 5);

                        session_start();

                }

                $this->login = new ClassLogin();
        }

        #Proteger contra roubo de sessão
        public function setSessionCanary($par=null){
                session_regenerate_id(true);
                if($par == null){
                        $_SESSION['canary']=[
                        "birth" => time(),
                        "IP" => TraitGetIp::getUserIp() //Pega o ip do usuario
                        ];

                }else{
                        $_SESSION['canary']['birth']=time();

                }
        }

        #Verificar a integridade da sessão
        public function verifyIdSessions(){
                if(!isset($_SESSION['canary'])){
                        $this->setSessionCanary();

                }

                if($_SESSION['canary']['IP'] !== TraitGetIp::getUserIp()){
                        $this->destructSessions();
                        $this->setSessionCanary();

                }

                if($_SESSION['canary']['birth'] < time() - $this->timeCanary){
                        $this->setSessionCanary("Time");

                }
        }

        #Setar as sessões do nosso sistema
        public function setSessions($Email){

                $this->verifyIdSessions();

                $_SESSION['Login']      = true;
                $_SESSION['Time']       = time();
                $_SESSION['Nome']       = $this->login->getIssetSession($Email)['data']['Nome'];
                $_SESSION['Email']      = $this->login->getIssetSession($Email)['data']['Email'];
                $_SESSION['Permissoes'] = $this->login->getIssetSession($Email)['data']['Permissoes'];

        }

        #Validar as páginas internas do sistema
        public function verifyInsideSession(){

                $this->verifyIdSessions();

                if(!isset($_SESSION['Login']) || !isset($_SESSION['Permissoes']) || !isset($_SESSION['canary'])){
                        $this->destructSessions();

                        header("Location: ".DIRPAGE."NaoAutorizado");

                }else{
                        if($_SESSION['Time'] >= time() - $this->timeSession){
                                $_SESSION['Time']=time();
                        }else{
                                $this->destructSessions();

                                header("Location: ".DIRPAGE."NaoAutorizado");

                        }
                }
        }

        #Destruir as sessions existentes
        public function destructSessions(){
                foreach (array_keys($_SESSION) as $key) {
                        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
                }
        }

        #testar
        public function testarSessions(){
                echo 'oiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooo';
        }

}
```

[image: Como funciona no google chorme]

[image: Como funciona no mozila]

Comment: O código é exatamente esse? Esses arquivos são executados diretamente pelo navegador?

Comment: Oi Anderson tenho a estrutura do controller o estranho se chamo tudo na tela de login funciona, mais se eu mando pra view de adm depois de logado ele perde as session

Comment: Então deve ter mais coisas influenciando. Tente simplificar na pergunta como tudo funciona, rotas, controladores, views, etc buscando fazer um [mcve].

Comment: Então é isso mesmo tudo funciona as rotas tudo ok ...... vou editar e colocar minha classe de session

Comment: Oi Anderson adicionei minha classe

Comment: Rodam direto no navegador...